# Quantifiable differences between RTOS kernels for small ARM microcontrollers

Tags: arm, microcontroller, rtos, freertos

There are many different RTOS available for microcontrollers. I am specifically looking for RTOS that support the ARM Cortex M processors. Also, I am not interested in closed source solutions.

Attempting to compare the relative merits of each RTOS from websites and mailing lists seems pretty difficult as they mostly seem to have equivalent features and do the same thing. The real differences become apparently only after trying to use each RTOS for some tasks.

I know this is somewhat subjective question and probably hard to answer - but there must be many people out there who have actually tried several different RTOS and formed an opinion of the relative merits of each one.

I am specifically interested in FreeRTOS, ChibiOS and Coocox CoOS, but other choices are also very welcome.

---

For example: it would seem that in ChibiOS, ISRs can call any system functions, but those calls must be wrapped in `chSysLockFromIsr()`/`chSysUnlockFromIsr()` and the code is not preemptable during those sections. In CoOS, the only functions callable are the ones starting with `isr_` such as `isr_PostSem()`, `isr_PostMail()`, `isr_PostQueueMail()` and 
`isr_SetFlag()`, but those functions internally use a service request queue which means most of the request is preemptable.

Comment: As per *Adi*, you need to quantify merits.  Does *Open Source* also mean royalty free?  Do you need a filesystem, a TCP/IP stack, is code size important, is interrupt latency, is support needed, etc.  As well as your list of three, eCos, vxWorks, RTEMS, Integrity, Nucleus, OS-9, MQX, QNX, embOS, ThreadX, TRON, MicroC/OS-II, etc.  Many come with source either by default or via asking for it.  BSD variants and Linux also can work.  Platform support for Cortex-M is usually very limited code (200-500 assembler lines).  Ie, it is easy to port any ARM OS to Cortex-M with source.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the features that one could take into account while choosing the RTOS:

- context-switch time
- interrupt latency
- synchronization mechanisms (flags, semaphores, mutexes, mailboxes, queues, ...)
- priority inversion handling
- memory management support (i.e. memory pools)
- scheduling policies support
- MMU support
- process support
- memory footprint
- efficiency of the kernel itself
- POSIX vs. non-POSIX API's
- software eco-system available (a.k.a middleware)
- ...

Which point(s) to put more focus, depends on the very application you're going to run. But generally, these are the things I can remember of which make difference between various RTOS's.