# What are the Parameters on which RTOS are compared?

Tags: rtos, keil, freertos, ucos

I want to compare two RTOS (e.g. -> Keil-RTX ,Ucos-iii and freertos), but I do not know on what parameters I need to compare them for e.g. Memory footprint, certified etc.

On which points do we compare RTOS ?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21697827/450609. Mostly, you should ask yourself why do _you_ want an RTOS (rather than bare metal) and then decide which RTOS best suits _your_ needs.

Comment: Try substituting "car" or "lunch" for "RTOS" then think how _you_ would respond to that question. If you don't know what you need, you should probably ask yourself why you want to compare anything in the first place (unless maybe you're researching for an RTOS edition of [Top Trumps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Trumps) - hey, I'd probably buy it :D)

Comment: Price/license, support, and familiarity.  The detailed technical differences aren't likely to matter unless you have extremely demanding requirements.

Comment: uC/OS is not one operating system - both uC/OS-II and uC/OS-III are actively marketed, and have different scheduling properties.  Are you intending to compare one or the other or both?

Answer (score 3):

You need to compare them on the parameters that are important to your application and meeting its requirements.  Those may include for example:

- Context switch time
- Message passing performance
- Scalability
- RAM footprint
- ROM footprint
- Heap usage
- OS primitives (queues, mutex, event-flags, semaphores, timer etc.)
- Scheduling algorithms (priority-preemptive, round-robin, cooperative)
- Per developer cost
- Per unit royalty cost
- Licence type/terms
- Source or object code provided
- Availability integrated middleware libraries (filesystem, USB, CAN, TCP/IP etc.)
- Safety certified
- Platform/target support
- RTOS aware debugger support
- RTOS/scheduling monitor/debug tools availability
- Vendor support
- Community support
- Documentation quality

The possible parameters are many, and only you can determine what is useful and important to your project.

I suggest selecting about five parameters important to your project, and then analysing each option using the [Kepner-Tregoe method](http://www.decision-making-confidence.com/kepner-tregoe-decision-making.html).  For each parameter you assign a weight based on its relative importance, you score each solution against each parameter, and then you sum the score x weight for an over all score.  The method takes some of the subjectivity out of selection and perhaps importantly provides evidence of your decision making process when you have to justify it to your boss.